# Getting duplicate message while retrieving messages from History

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

I'm created group chat in Openfire & XMPP.

I'm getting history from Openfire server using "since" while joining room.
Here is my code :

```
XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:chatWithUser];

xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomStorage
                                             jid:roomJID
                                   dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppRoom activate:self.xmppStream];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self
        delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];

[history addAttributeWithName:@"since" stringValue:finalDate];

[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:self.xmppStream.myJID.user
                        history:history
                       password:nil];
```

I store message in local so next time user when login it fetch last message date from local and send it to server to fetch all message after that date.

```
finalDate is date from that i fetch from local and send it to server.
```

But what happern is that when i send `finalDate` to server it fetch last message also that i already stored in local database.

If my last message from localDB is 'Hi' and date '2016-08-08T04:52:42.347Z' than it fetch 'Hi' from server.

Why this happen ? I want message from server after date.

Comment: it gives you greater or equal to value .. means whatever you put in history date if its same as last message it gives you that too ..

Comment: how to overcome it?

Comment: add some seconds in final date ....

Comment: if you overcome from your problem .. you need to do this ... otherwise check for duplicate entry of message ..

Comment: yes, so there's no solution for that ?

Comment: check for duplication on recieve message ...

Comment: ok thanx for help.. i added 0.1 second and seems fine ... i also work on check duplication msg.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of XMPP MUC specification is - history messages are stamped with server time, while you ask `since` your local time. There is an `XMPPAutoTime` module in XMPPFramework, which trying to track time difference and you should add that difference for any timestamp-based queries. Check the detailed description [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Extensions/XEP-0202/XMPPAutoTime.h)

Comment: i used zero timestamp to fetch history.